# Theorem 2.13 in Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

I am having trouble understanding "For every fixed $b$, the set of pairs $(b,a)$ is equivalent to $A$..."

Suppose we take $n=3$ but $A=\{1,2\}$ since the elements need not be distinct. Then $$B_{n-1}=\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1)\}$$ and $$B_{n}= \{ ((1,1),1),((2,2),1),((1,2),1),((2,1),1),((1,1),2),((2,2),2),((1,2),2),((2,1),2) \} $$

Clearly, $$|A|\neq|B_{n}|$$

I don't understand how it follows then $A$ is equivalent to the set of all pairs $b,a$. A similar question is asked here but isn't the same at all :[Theorem 2.13 in Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447815/theorem-2-13-in-walter-rudins-principles-of-mathematical-analysis)  Can someone help with what part I am overlooking? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's basically saying for a fixed $b$ there is a bijection between the set of $(b, a)$ and $A.$ So in your example take any $b$ say $(1, 1).$ "The set of pairs $(b, a)$" would then be $((1, 1), 1), ((1, 1), 2).$

Comment: @ntntnt That still isn't bijective

Comment: I think the main idea Rudin is trying to convey is the bijection. Is the bijection clear to you? Also countable is countably infinite. So I'm not sure what you are trying to say with $|A| \neq |B_n|.$

Comment: $((1, 1), 1) \rightarrow 1, ((1, 1), 2) \rightarrow 2.$

Comment: Thanks. I got it. What was unclear was that he meant countably infinite. But I was just trying to say that there cardinalities weren't equal but I see that isn't a case of theorem. Take care.

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers mate.

Comment: As a side note: He said for every FIXED b, the b you gave is not fixed. With what ntntnt, said you should have it down. I would also recommend thinking about why he said every word, because most of the words are not superfluous, and are important. Just think of math proofs as legalistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudin is asserting that for each fixed $b\in B_{n-1}$, there is a bijection between the set
$$
E_b=\{(b,a)\in B_n:a\in A\}
$$
and $A$ given by
$$
(b,a)\mapsto a.
$$
Since $B_{n-1}$ is countable by hypothesis, this proves that $B = \bigcup_{b\in B_{n-1}}E_b$ is a countable union of countable sets, and is thereby countable.